# Shortest undefined behavior sample in C++

Tags: code-challenge, c++

What's the shortest, well-formed C++ code that exhibits undefined behavior?

Comment: What do you mean "runnable"? If it has UB, there's no guarantee it can be run.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes well, I mean that it starts.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore that is very dependent on the compiler (version).

Comment: Define "exhibits". Does it need to show something? Or is it enough that the internal memory state is undefined at some point during the program?

Comment: defined "well-formed".

Answer (score 12):

```
int main(){main;}
```

> #### 3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]
>
> 3 - [...] The function main shall not be used within a program.

Edit: this is diagnosable, so not UB.

---

```
int main(){for(;;);}
```

> #### 1.10 Multi-threaded executions and data races [intro.multithread]
>
> 24 - The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one of the following:
>   — terminate,
>   — make a call to a library I/O function,
>   — access or modify a volatile object, or
>   — perform a synchronization operation or an atomic operation.

---

```
int main(){int i=i;}
```

> #### 4.1 Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion [conv.lval]
>
> 1 - [...] If the object to which the glvalue refers is [...] uninitialized, a program
>   that necessitates this conversion has undeﬁned behavior.

---

```
//^L.
```

Here `^L` is the form feed character, which is part of the basic character set.  4 characters (a newline is not required per 2.2:2).  Undefined behaviour is per

> #### 2.8 Comments [lex.comment]
>
> 1 - If there is a
>   form-feed or a vertical-tab character in [a `//`-style] comment, only white-space characters shall appear between it
>   and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required.

Comment: the second one's not undefined. It can optimize out the for loop without issue. That is not undefined behavior.

Comment: @rubenvb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x - *anytime the standard says "the compiler may assume P," it is implied that a program which has the property not-P has undefined semantics*.

Comment: yet the compiler may also assume no side effects when eliding copy constructors.

Comment: @rubenvb because that particular case is *explicitly* mentioned.

Comment: @rubenvb 12.8:31 says *an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class
object, even if the copy/move constructor and/or destructor for the object have side eﬀects*. "assume" is not in the language.

Comment: I believe the rule at §3.6.1 is *diagnosable*, so your first is ill-formed.

Comment: @Jerry is right. §3.6.1 has no mention that no diagnostic is required or that the behaviour is undefined. That makes it indeed diagnosable.

Comment: the for(;;) is exactly the loop I use in my embedded project..so not at all undefined, but rather strong, optimized and very useful

Comment: @BogdanAlexandru your embedded project has undefined behaviour.  That means that it might work as you expect now, but when you upgrade your compiler it will behave differently.

Answer (score 5):

```
\u\
0000
```

This has eight characters, and has undefined behaviour, according to §2.2/1.

> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a
>   new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form
>   logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source
>   line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. If, as a
>   result, a character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>   universal-character-name is produced, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: this isn't & "program". A program has a `main`.

Comment: @rubenvb Try it on Hell++. It has undefined behaviour, so can be a program without a `main`. It's hard to enforce rules when you ask for a program that doesn't have any rules to follow (that's what UB means!).

Comment: Based on the wording of the question, I think this qualifies -- it asks only for the shortest "code" that displays UB. Based on the "runnable" in the comment, I think the intent, however, was the shortest *program*, which would rule out your code, because according to §3.6.1/1: "A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program." As such, without `main`, what you have is ill-formed.

Comment: @JerryCoffin He is using a freestanding environment where main is not required. You conveniently left out the rest of §3.6.1/1 which says "It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
function.". This is a valid program ("valid" as in it's a "program" according to your argument).

Comment: Dang, just came here to bring that one. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
int main(){int i=1>>-1;}
```

Explanation:

C++98 and C++11 §5.8/1 both state that

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Comment: on a 32-bit system, isnt the length in bits of `int` typically 32? changing the RHS of the shift to `-1` is the same number of chars and won't depend on integer sizes

Answer (score 2):

```
#include. /*Imagine a new-line right after the dot*/
```

§16.2/4:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> `#include` 
>   *pp-tokens   new-line*
>
> (that does not match one of the two previous forms) is permitted. [..]
>   If the directive resulting after all replacements does not match one
>   of the two previous forms, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Won't it parse the same if you remove the space before the dot?

Comment: @feersum Yep. That doesn't alter the idea, which is why I avoided it to enhance readability, but I guess it serves the point of the question to illustrate that the space can be omitted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If one is to believe wikipedia, here's a few:

Modifying strings is said to cause undefined behavior. It's always worked for me.

```
int main(int c,char*v){v[0]='.';}
```

A non-void function with no return causes undefined return values.

```
int a(){}
int main(){return a();}
```

Division (of int?) by zero is supposedly undefined. All I know is that it crashes.

```
int main(int c){c/0;}
```

Comment: These are not legal code snippets. Main must be defined as `int main(){}` at the very least.

Comment: Damn, I was sure the question was about C. Sorry about that.

Comment: @shiona the second parameter should be `char **` not `char *`. You're merely modifying part of a pointer value. In fact, `argv` is guaranteed to be safely modifiable.

Comment: The standard allows string *literals* to be read-only, so many implementations do that.  It's correct for `char *argv[]` to not have any `const` qualifiers.  You could crash by writing into a string literal with `int main(){char *v="";*v=1;}`

Answer (score -1):

```
int main() { int* a; return a[0]; }
```